# Use of little other than

Tags: phrase-meaning

In a book, I came across a sentence

> The UK economist John Maynard Keynes (1883–1946), for example, argued that the world is ruled **by little other than** the ideas of economic theorists and political philosophers.

I was not able to understand the meaning of the highlighted text.

Answer (score 2):

I see why you're having difficulties. The dictionaries aren't very clear on this.

Here's one I found to be relatively good:
https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/no-nothing-little-more-than

Basically it means that:

> the world is ruled by the ideas of economic theorists and political philosophers **and not much else.**

Or maybe to put it even simpler

> the primary rulers of the world are the ideas of economic theorists and political philosophers and there is a small chance that some other ideas have some influence.